# Trigger to update a table with timestamp when data is inserted into another table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am very new to triggers. need help here.

I have two tables, `[dbo].[Demand_Request]` and `[dbo].[Modified_Demand_Request]`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Demand_Request] 
(
    [CASE_ID] [INT] NULL,
    [TE_PART_NUMBER] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [VALUE] [FLOAT] NULL,
    [DEMAND_DATE] [DATETIME] NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Modified_Demand_Request] 
(
    [CASE_ID] [INT] NULL,
    [TE_PART_NUMBER] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [VALUE] [FLOAT] NULL,
    [DEMAND_DATE] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [Modified_On] [DATETIME] NULL
)
```

When data is inserted into `[dbo].[Demand_Request]`, I want to add the same data into table `[dbo].[Modified_Demand_Request]` along with a timestamp.

Below is my trigger, but it is not working:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Modified_Demand_Request1]
ON [dbo].[Demand_Request]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
     INSERT INTO [dbo].[Modified_Demand_Request] ([CASE_ID], [TE_PART_NUMBER],[VALUE], [DEMAND_DATE], [Modified_On])
         SELECT 
             [CASE_ID], [TE_PART_NUMBER], [VALUE],
             [DEMAND_DATE], GETDATE()
         FROM 
             INSERTED
```

Comment: You trigger is defined as `after update` so it won't trigger on `insert`. For that you need `after insert, update`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server trigger insert values from new row into another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247679/sql-server-trigger-insert-values-from-new-row-into-another-table)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `FOR INSERT`

```
Create Trigger [dbo].[Modified_Demand_Request1]
   on [dbo].[Demand_Request]
   FOR INSERT
   AS
     Insert Into[dbo].[Modified_Demand_Request] ([CASE_ID],[TE_PART_NUMBER],[VALUE],[DEMAND_DATE],[Modified_On])
       SELECT [CASE_ID],[TE_PART_NUMBER],[VALUE],[DEMAND_DATE],GETDATE()
       FROM INSERTED
```

for DEMO [REXTESTER](https://rextester.com/PPB15771)

Extra Reference: [Firing Trigger for Bulk Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11502470/2750968)

Comment: @parthaburagohain I have updated the answer with demo link, i hope it is working as expected, can you please elaborate your issue?

Comment: hi, The trigger works when i am trying to insert one line. but when i run the it for multiple lines , it does not work.. How can i achieve using bulk insert ?

Comment: @parthaburagohain what happens when you insert multiple rows? The code looks correct as its selecting from `inserted` which will contain all inserted rows.

Comment: Nothing is copied from the base table when i try to insert multiple rows.

Comment: Hmmm... might require some investigation... you can debug a trigger using select statements and print statements if you insert the data from SSMS and from that work out what is/isn't happening.

Comment: @parthaburagohain may I know how are you inserting data into table? using `select` statement or a simple `insert` statement?, triggers fire once per statement, not once per row.

Comment: or try using a cursor? insert values into a cursor from `INSERTED` and run look for the cursor? might help, however using of cursors is not advised.

Answer (score 0):

May I know that how you are inserting the data. I tried the same as below (with "FOR INSERT" trigger) and able to get the data in Modified_Demand_Request table.

```
    insert into [Demand_Request] values(1,'Test',1.0,GETDATE())
    insert into [Demand_Request] values(2,'Test1',1.0,GETDATE())
    insert into [Demand_Request] values(3,'Test2',1.0,GETDATE())
    insert into [Demand_Request] values(14,'Test2',1.0,GETDATE())
```